# Pass variable from a form to other when closing

Tags: c#

I am developing an app which requires to close and open different winforms over time. I faced a problem, how can I pass a variable, in this case a SerialPort that has been opened in an initial form?

Forms are opened from Program.cs

```
Application.Run(new Auth());
Application.Run(new Main());
```

Auth.cs code includes this:

```
SerialPort RCU = new SerialPort();
RCU.PortName = textbox.Text; //Port name is get from user input
```

And I want to use this port in the other form "Main".

Is there any possibility to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You could send it on the formclosing event?

Comment: @EpicKip I am closing the form just with -- this.Close(); --. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just ask for a `Auth` object in your `Main` constructor and then initialize them in that order:

```
Auth auth = new Auth();
Main main = new Main(auth);
Application.Run(auth);
Application.Run(main);
```

Then in `Main` you can save that object and get the property once set:

```
public Main(Auth auth)
{
  AuthWindow = auth;
}

public Auth AuthWindow {get; set;}

// later..
AuthWindow.RCU
```

Note though, two `Application.Run` calls isn't the way you want to go, just create a new `Auth` form and show it the moment the main form is loaded.

Comment: This works for simple variables, but in my case doesn't, as it is a SerialPort, the compiler blocks because of its security. Is there any possibility on fixing this?

Comment: "_Blocks because of its security_" What do you even mean by that?

Comment: Error CS0122: 'PROPERTY NAMES' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: So then change it to `public` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that, I'm currently learning and I have this ridiculous mistakes ;) Thanks for your help